# Why is the <form> tag a "variable scope boundary" for ASP.NET inline code?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, inline-code

Consider the following two minimal examples.

Example 1:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <% string x = "Hello World"; %>
        <%= x %>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Example 2:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <% string x = "Hello World"; %>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <%= x %>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Example 1 compiles and runs as expected, example 2 does not even compile:

> CS0103: The name 'x' does not exist in the current context. (Line `<%= x %>`)

Why? Is the server-side `form` tag some magic "variable scope boundary"? If yes, where is this documented?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because all elements that have `runat=server` tag are? Below sample will also not run.

```
<% string x = "Hello World"; %>
<div id="TestDiv" runat="server">
    <%= x %>
</div>
```

Probably because of the [page life cycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx). The aspx code is the last to be rendered while the (contents of) objects with runat=server can be used in code behind and need to be accessible there. `x` is not available there since it is only declared on the page at a later time.

Note: this is just my guess.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `runat="server"` attribute to any tag (other than `form` tag) in ASP.NET PAGE then you're basically **Parsing** the content inside the tag at server side. And the PAGE is defined under the [System.Web.UI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page(v=vs.110).aspx) class which has a different context.

The [Form](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.form(v=vs.110).aspx) tag is defined under the context of simple static HTML tag.

That's why you're not able to compile this:

```
<% string x = "Hello World"; %>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <%= x %>
</form>
```